# dealing with paths in unix loops

Tags: loops, unix, path, samtools

Relative unix newbie.  I have a number of directories (`Sample*/`), within which I want to merge all raw.sort.bam files using samtools.  I have working code to do this within each directory, but I want to deal with all directories at once by running code from the parent directory.  My problem is that I’m forced to call up samtools with a full path, and I’m having trouble figuring out how this path will work within a unix loop.

First, here’s my working code for merging and converting from within each directory:

```
/home/user/pathtosamtools/sam merge -o all.sort.bam *raw.sort.bam
```

Now, my NON-working code attempting to do this for all directories when run from the parent directory:

```
for f in `ls Sample*/`; do /home/user/pathtosamtools/sam merge -o $f all.sort.bam Sample*/*raw.sort.bam; done
```

Errors:

```
[bam_merge_core_ext] fail to open file all.sort.bam
[bam_header_read] bgzf_check_EOF: Invalid argument
[bam_header_read] invalid BAM binary header (this is not a BAM file).
Segmentation fault
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

```
for dir in Sample*/; do 
    /home/user/pathtosamtools/sam merge -o "$dir/all.sort.bam" "$dir"/*raw.sort.bam
done
```

You provide the glob pattern in the for loop.

For safety, [always quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667).

Comment: That works, a thousand thanks!  Also thank you for some best-practices pointers.  Lots left to learn.